# ef core plus: ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: property

Tags: entity-framework-core, entity-framework-plus

With ef core plus, I'm trying to update a set of rows on my model:

```
await _context.Set<Critique>()
            .Include(c => c.User)
            .Where(c => c.Closed && c.User.Id == user.Id)
            .UpdateAsync(c => new Critique() { User = deletedUser });
```

Here I get the following Exception:

> ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: property
>   Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Utilities.Check.NotNull(T value, string parameterName) in Check.cs, line 21
>
> TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
>   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(object target, object[] arguments, Signature sig, bool constructor, bool wrapException

When I just load the data with ef core, it loads the 1 row I expect

```
var test = await _context.Set<Critique>()
            .Where(c => c.Closed && c.User.Id == user.Id)
            .ToArrayAsync();
```

The database model is nothing fancy but is too large to post here. I'm using [Required] extensively, and there are plenty of One-to-Many relations.

(Btw, user.Id is not null and available, and deletedUser is also available both in code and in the database.)

How should this error be interpreted? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our library can update value but cannot update value using navigation property at this moment

This doesn't work

```
.UpdateAsync(c => new Critique() { User = deletedUser });
```

But this would have worked if you had the property

```
.UpdateAsync(c => new Critique() { UserID = deletedUserID });
```

Also, there is no point to add `.Include(c => c.User)` since you don't retrieve this information.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to answer!
Yes, the Include was an action of despair.
Alright, thanks for the clarification!